# php mysqli prepared statement all ways skipping the first result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, fetch

I have a class which takes data from the database. Everything works but the results 'clips' the first result.
 For example I have 15 items in my database so by echoing out the id I should get

1
2
3
4
...
13 
14 
15

But I get 
2
3
4
...
13 14 15

The statement is working as the data is displaying but why is it all ways missing the first result.

CODE:

```
private function formatResults($data){
        while($row = $data->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['product_id'].'<br/>';
        }
    }

    public function getAllProducts(){
        if($this->databaseConnection()){
            $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->formatResults($stmt);
        }
    }
```

That is the original function which works, (except missing out the first row).
I also tried just targeting one row to see if it made a difference but no nothing gets returned.

```
public function getAllProducts(){
        if($this->databaseConnection()){
            $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ? ORDER BY product_id ASC");
            $a =1;
            $stmt->bindParam(1,$a,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo $row['product_id'].'<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Im not sure what to do here, the function appears to work.

Comment: Why are you putting a backslash in front of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` ?

Comment: Don't know, throws an error if i don't 
"Fatal error: Class 'classLib\products\PDO'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're fetching/throwing away a row:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  // fetch first row
$this->formatResults($stmt);                // fetch all the other rows
```

Simply eliminate that "fetch first row" line.